# Compare list with string in Python and highlight matches

Tags: python, list, compare, string-formatting

I'm trying to compare a python list with a string and highlight matches with mark inside a new string.
But it won't work. Following example:

```
my_string = 'This is my string where i would find matches of my List'
my_list = ['THIS IS', 'WOULD FIND', 'BLA', 'OF MY LIST']
result_that_i_need = '<mark>This is</mark> my string where i <mark>would find</mark> matches <mark>of my List</mark>'
```

Has anybody any idea how to solve this? Can somebody help me please?

I tried following:

```
my_string = 'This is my string where i would find matches of my List'
my_string_split = string.split()

my_list = ['This is', 'would find', 'bla', 'of my List']
input_list=[]
for my_li in my_list:
    if my_li in my_string:
        input_list.append(my_li)

input_list_join = " ".join(input_list)

new_list = []

for my_string_spl in my_string_split:
    if my_string_spl in input_list_join:
        new_list.append('<mark>'+ my_string_spl + '</mark>')
    else:
        new_list.append(my_string_spl)

result = " ".join(new_list)
print(result)
```

Comment: Please add your attempt at solving the problem this problem.

Comment: you may not want to call your list and string list and string

Comment: Thank you pygeek and Chris i changed the code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
my_string = 'This is my string where i would find matches of my List'
my_list = ['This is', 'would find', 'bla', 'of my List']

result = my_string
for match in my_list:
  if match in my_string:
    result = result.replace(match, '<mark>' + match + '</mark>')

print(result)
```

Output:

```
<mark>This is</mark> my string where i <mark>would find</mark> matches <mark>of my List</mark>
```

Comment: Thank you very much i also tried this solution but if my_list contains for example 'is my' as well the result would not be shown because the first match was 'This is' and was replaced with <mark>This is</mark> -> now 'my' stands alone and offers no match with 'is my'... do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes, I see. If you have overlapping matches in `my_list`, perhaps you can try to merge them first and then try the above method, e.g. iterate over `my_list` and check if the end of one match is the same as the beginning of another, thus `['This is', 'is my', 'foo']` would become `['This is my', 'foo']`.

Comment: @PApostol That's not entirely correct. You would need to ensure that the substring isn't also present independently in another part of the larger string.

Comment: Also, your if statement is unnecessary.

Comment: @pygeek true, but not that simple. What if you have `['Hello nice person', 'nice']` and your string is `Hello nice person, it is nice to meet you`?

Comment: I agree the `if` statement will not affect the result but personally I like it for clarity. Please feel free to post your answer, I have no idea how to tackle the edge cases effectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! To make it more complicated i edited the code inside the List in uppercase. But the result should only effect on the long string with add the <mark>. That's what i really nead. Hope somebody has a nice idea to solve this issue.